# get text from first column tabel with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with 5 columns and a lot of rows. For each row i want to see the text that in the first column. (this is html) i found some examples with jquery but can't get it to work with my code. Can someone help me with the answer? the jquery code is in the get_date(f) function on line 45

i cant get the code to word properly in this textbox so i put an online link here: http://wietskekoelma.com/test/highteabestellijst.html

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code showing what you've tried, in your question.

Comment: i've tried alot of things for example this: $('tr').find(td:first).text() or $('tr').find(td:nth-child(3n+1)).text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/6L7Lb9pt/)**

```
$(".mainTable tr").each(function () {
    lst += $(this).children().eq(0).text() + "  ";
});
```

**Refer**

1. [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
2. [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
3. [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

**UPDATE**

```
order_data += $(".mainTable tr").eq(i).children().eq(0).text() + " = "+f.line[i].value +" Stuks\n";
```

Comment: How can i inplement this whole code in to this line: order_data += "CODE FOR CALLING FIRST COLUMN" + " = "+f.line[i].value +" Stuks\n"; if i know that i can see if it works. (im not that much experienced with jqeury.)

Comment: Thank you! it works but now i have one problem i get all the time.. it looks like is't looping through the column and that puts in every row the data from all the rows. i hope you understand what i mean?